# YouTube account linking, v3 of API

Tags: ios, youtube-api

Our iOS app uploads to YouTube and has recently been updated to the 3.0 API and iOS SDK. The biggest thorn we've had with users is the whole "account linking" issue (wish this was indicated and set up when the user signs into their YouTube account).

I've been trying to figure out a way to positively determine if the account is linked right after they sign in and, if not linked, send them to a UIWebView with the linking page. My bright idea was to get the channel info for the user and if the title is blank then that means it hasn't been linked/setup yet. That worked great when I wrote the code a couple weeks ago. Testing it today it now comes back with an "Unauthorized" response.

I'm reluctant to rely on that error being the indicator that they aren't linked. Any other, more reliable ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way on v3 to know if the user has his/her google account linked to youtube account is to make a channels.list() call and then check for channels.status.isLinked

(see: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4846#c1)

For example:

```
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForChannelsListWithPart:@"status"];

channelListTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                         completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                             GTLYouTubeChannelListResponse *channelList,
                                             NSError *error) {

                             if ([[channelList items] count] > 0) {

                                 GTLYouTubeChannel *channel = channelList[0];
                                 NSLog(@"%@", channel.status.isLinked); // 0 if not linked, 1 if linked

                             [...]
                             }
}];
```